# sed formatting double quotes single quotes

Tags: regex, sed, quotes

I'm using sed to replace a word in a text.xml.

The text.xml looks like this:

```
some line
<state name='generate'>
    notify
</state>
some line
```

I'm trying to replace the word 'notify' with caller'
The command I have so far is:

```
sed -i "/<state name=\'generate\'>/,/<\/state>/s/notify/caller/" ./test.xml
```

I am giving sed a range of lines between  and . Between those lines is the word 'notify' which I am replacing with caller.

I'm unsure if this is a quoting problem. Insight is appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: I got it to work by removing the escape characters around generate.

```
sed -i "/<state name='generate'>/,/<\/state>/s/notify/caller/" ./test.xml
```

Does anyone know the reason behind it?

Comment: It seems you don't need to escape single quotes when using double quotes to sandwich the entire expression. I tried the first command you tried with single quote sandwiching instead and the shell seemed to be waiting on something..Not quite sure.

Comment: You need an escape character when using a single quote once. If you have two, they cancel themselves out, as there is a beginning and an end.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you don't need to escape single quotes when using double quotes to sandwich the entire expression... –  Siddhartha

I got it to work by removing the escape characters around generate. –  user2661842

Comment: I appreciate what you're trying to do here but as it stands this doesn't really make an answer. Can you take a bit of time to edit it into better shape please?